# Dynamically test generating in Java or Scala

Tags: json, scala, junit, scalatest, specs2

I have a big json file with list of tests. Json file contains several filenames, which contains names of test classes, which have some setup stuff and a list of tests. Here is an example of such json file:

```
{
   "filename1.py": {
     "ClassName": [
       "setupSection": [
         here will be list of sqls which should be performed before tests
        ],
   "listOfTests": {
     "test1Name": [
        { here will be query }, {here will be expected result}
     ],
     "test1Name": [
        { here will be query }, {here will be expected result}
     ]
    }
   },
  "filename2.py": {
     "ClassName": [
       "setupSection": [
         here will be list of sqls which should be performed before tests
        ],
   "listOfTests": {
     "test1Name": [
        { here will be query }, {here will be expected result}
     ],
     "test1Name": [
        { here will be query }, {here will be expected result}
     ]
    }
   }
}
```

And I need somehow perform this tests with a few classes written in Java or Scala. So there should be 1-3 classes written in Java or/and Scala which will perform all tests from json file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using [specs2](http://specs2.org). Let's say you can deserialize your Json file to

```
case class Query(query: Query)
case class Test(name: String, query: Query, result: String)
case class TestFile(setup: Query, tests: List[Test])
```

Then you can create the following specification

```
import org.specs2._

class JsonSpec(path: String) extends Specification {
   lazy val files: List[TestFile] = readFilesFromJson(path)

   def createTests(tests: List[Test]): Fragments = 
     Fragments.foreach(tests) { test =>
       s2"""|
            |${test.name ! executeQuery(test.query) must_== test.result}""".stripMargin
     }

   def is = 
     Fragments.foreach(files) { file =>
     s2"""|
          |${step(executeQuery(file.setup))}
          |${createTests(file.tests) 
     """.stripMargin
   }

   // load the Json file
   def readFilesFromJson(path: String): List[TestFile] =
     ???

   // execute the query and return the result
   // as a String
   def executeQuery(query: Query): String = 
     ???
}
```

If you have any issue with that please create a small Github project and I can help you from there.